# How to apply copy function on a icon javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, copy, click, icons

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

strong text**

I have a copy icon in a website. I want to copy the website URL when I click the icon. the traditional method is working on input text but I failed to apply it on an icon.

```
            <div class="icon-container" style="display: inline-block;">
            <input class="paste" type="button" value="Copy Url" @click="urlCopy" id="copy" hidden/>
             <textarea class="paste" id="url" rows="1" cols="30" hidden></textarea>
            <img  style="display: inline-block" src="share.png" alt="">
        </div>


urlCopy() {
  console.log("sulg", this.slug.fullPath)
  let Url = document.getElementById("url");
  Url.innerHTML = window.location.href;
  console.log(Url.innerHTML)
  Url.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

}
```

Comment: can you write your codebase?

Comment: i'm not sure if you want the function to copy the text to the clipboard.

Comment: Yes I want to copy the current url. but when I click in the icon.

Comment: update your whole codebase with css on javascript/html/css snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use `vue-clipboard2`. It will make copy url much easier than traditional method.

**Example**

```html
  <div id="app"></div>
 
  <template id="t">
    <div class="container">
    <input type="text" v-model="message">
    <button type="button" @click="doCopy">Copy!</button>
    </div>
  </template>
 
  <script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '#t',
    data: function () {
      return {
        message: 'Copy These Text'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      doCopy: function () {
        this.$copyText(this.message).then(function (e) {
          alert('Copied')
          console.log(e)
        }, function (e) {
          alert('Can not copy')
          console.log(e)
        })
      }
    }
  })
  </script>
```

Comment: can it be apply on img tag? on click img it will copy the url

Comment: Yes you can. You can also wrap `img` tag with `button` tag.
 `<img  style="display: inline-block" src="share.png" alt="" @click="doCopy">` or `<button @click="doCopy"> <img  style="display: inline-block" src="share.png" alt=""></button>`